# How to display name onmouseover in a marker : Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added multiple marker in my google map using google map library.It's working properly but my issue is that, i want to display a name onmouseover of a marker.And i have tried like this.

Code:

```
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $rs){
    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = $data['tunnelsname'][$i]->name;
    $marker['onmouseover'] = 'hii';
    $x = $data['tunnelsname'][$i]->name;
    $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$data['tunnelsname'][$i]->name));
    $id = $data['tunnelsname'][$i]->id;
    $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<a href = "'.BASEURL.'tunnel/'.$name.'/'.$id.'">'.$x.'</a>';
    $marker['clickable'] = TRUE; 
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    $i++;
    }
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

I am trying to display hii onmouseover on each marker.But unable to get a desirable result.Please help me to get this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe user interaction such as "mouseover" are much easier to implement using **client-side implementation**. Check **[When to use client-side geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies#client)** and **[When to use server-side geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies#server)**.

Sample code:

```
marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent('<p>hii</p>');
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

// assuming you also want to hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
});
```

Check **[Maps JavaScript API
 Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)** for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The easy, already implemented way to display a short text onmouseover is to use the marker "title" property. You can use it direct in the basic marker definition:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: x.x, lng: x.x},
      title: 'hii',
  map: map
});
```

or do it later using the property:

```
marker.setTitle('hii')
```